# Best practice to integrate Asp.net Forms Authentication tables with my own domain tables?

Tags: asp.net-membership

I am creating a Asp.Net site which will accept users' registration/logon. The Asp.Net MVC automatically generate the following tables in a database with a strange name of `aspnet-MyProjectName-20120705215524`.

Is it possible to let Asp.Net Mvc generate the tables in my own database? (I have other tables which will refer the `Users` table). I will need the more columns in the table `Users`. Can I just manually add the columns to it? *And I also want the extra columns show in the registration page.*

---

**Update** 
What's the best practice of integrating the system generated Users tables?

1. Memberships
2. Profiles
3. Roles
4. Users
5. UsersInRoles

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [ApplicationId]    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [UserId]           UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [UserName]         NVARCHAR (50)    NOT NULL,
    [IsAnonymous]      BIT              NOT NULL,
    [LastActivityDate] DATETIME         NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [UserApplication] FOREIGN KEY ([ApplicationId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Applications] ([ApplicationId])
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the aspnet_regsql.exe tool this will generate the application services database for you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(v=vs.80).aspx

You could add columns to the default database but I'm not on the effects of that, most of the app services use stored procedures so you could extend them